# How to make a DataGrid Template with code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make this XAML template using only C# :

```
<DataGrid AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="6,78,9,47" Name="datagrid_Jobs">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Job" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Score}" Header="Score" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Perecent Complete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Slider Margin="5" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Value="{Binding Path=Score, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I just want to define the grid in XAML, and I want to make the whole template by C#.
I don't know where to start.

Comment: [Creating DataTemplates in Code, The Right Way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `FrameworkElementFactory` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx)).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="6,78,9,47" Name="datagrid_Jobs"
          Loaded="datagrid_Jobs_Loaded">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Job" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Score}" Header="Score" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="pcColumn" Header="Perecent Complete" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public void datagrid_Jobs_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElementFactory sliderHolder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Slider));
    sliderHolder.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, new Binding("Score") { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
    sliderHolder.SetValue(Slider.MarginProperty, new Thickness(5));
    sliderHolder.SetValue(Slider.MaximumProperty, (double)100);
    sliderHolder.SetValue(Slider.MinimumProperty, (double)0);
    var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    dataTemplate.VisualTree = sliderHolder;
    dataTemplate.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);
    pcColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
}
```

Comment: so whenever i want to make a column template i gotta use **`FrameworkElementFactory`** to create it the way i need, right?

Comment: Yes, you should use `FrameworkElementFactory` if you want to do that in code but the better option is XAML.

Answer (score 2):

I think that all you need is on this website check it:

http://harishasanblog.blogspot.ca/2011/01/create-datagrid-in-wpf-using-code.html